# Run code from Java file in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a java file as this

```
    public class Execute {

    public void run(){
        try{
            Runtime runtimeInstance = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = runtimeInstance.exec("cmd /c D:\\Data\\Personal\\abu\\CobaAppFuse\\ExecuteCLI\\src\\java\\cli\\abu.bat");
            System.out.print(p);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.print(ex);
        }


    }
}
```

how do I run the file when my jsp file path??

file JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="abu.execute.cli.Execute" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table align="center" border="3">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to run java file when the submit button is pressed
thank you....

Comment: *how do I run the file when my jsp file path??* --> Elaborate on this. Not clear

Comment: I didn't downvote, but since there is no comment on the downvote, I'll do that: your question is lacking quality, please read the [how to ask][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask] section. Your question needs to set the problem into a context, the problem has to be clear, and the code provided needs to be as small as possible while still being complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want to execute the procedure whenever someone accesses JSP-File x.jsp.

While it is possible to run Java code form inside a JSP-File, I would never recommend it. You might ask why, but this has been documented better than I ever could in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) post.

To answer your question, you need to create a servlet

```
@WebServlet("/YourServlet")
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public YourServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      new Execute.run();
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/_search.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Furthermore you will have to change the permissions of your webapp. Which is documented on this [page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html).

Mind that this is the most basic approach, not the cleanest one. Usually execution of any java code *(that controls the execution plan)* is done within services. You can add a service to you application by (agian) declaring a HttpServlet and declaring a service there.

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        new Execute.run();

        if (view.equals(request.getPathInfo().substring(1)) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/" + view + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(view);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("Executing action failed.", e);
    }
}
```

While I don't know what the comment below means, I'll add the html-code to the answer to make it more complete. In practice this would mean:

On submit the html needs to make an HTTP-Post to the servlet.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table align="center" border="3">
            <tr>
                <td><form action='Myactionhandle'><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/></form></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the servlet has to execute the code.

```
@WebServlet("/Myactionhandle")
    public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public YourServlet() {
            super();
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          new Execute.run();
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/_search.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: jsp file for her as what?? because I was confused when the jsp call servlet file,??

Comment: @AbuYazidBustomi I edited my answer. But I really suggest you start reading a tutorial on Java Web development.

Answer (score -1):

Add javascript in your JSP. On click of the button, call the function where you can execute the java class by creating an object using scriptlets.

Comment: You can not call a java class method from javascript by adding scritlet.